# I need an alternative to AppendTo using Reap and Sow

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap

```
c = Table[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/2], 3], 3]
d = Total[c, {2}]
list = {};
For[k = 0, k <= Length[d], k++, 
If[d[[k]] == 2, AppendTo[list, c[[k]]]]]
```

This is my code. I want to use reap and sow in place of AppendTo. How should I go about it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `Select[c, 2 == Total[#] &]`

Comment: Alright thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) or [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) instead:

```
SeedRandom[1]
c = Table[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[1/2], 3], 10]
```

> {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0,
>      0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}

```
d = Total[c, {2}]
```

> {2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2}

```
list = {};
For[k = 0, k <= Length[d], k++, If[d[[k]] == 2, AppendTo[list, c[[k]]]]]; list
```

> {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}

```
Pick[c, d, 2]
```

> {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}

```
Select[c, Total[#] == 2 &]
```

> {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}